# Sphere in tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, spheres

Construct a straight tetrahedron with each face being a right triangle and the right angle is in the vertex of the tetrahedron. If this tetrahedron has a height of $2$, find the radius of the sphere that is inscribed in a tetrahedron.

I try by using some elementary geometry and it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: Perhaps you can start by explaining some details that are unclear to me. What is a "straight tetrahedron"? If *all* faces are right triangles, then what does it mean for "the" right angle to be in "the" vertex? And the height of $2$ is relative to *which* face? ... Also, you should include the elementary geometry that didn't work, so that others don't waste time duplicating a doomed approach. (Alternatively, someone may see a way to adjust your work to get at the answer.) Include all clarifications in the body of the question; comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.

Comment: Can you be more **specific** and clear about the faces of the tetrahedron ?

Comment: A straight tetrahedron is a tetrahedron the height is on the surface of the tetrahedron.

Comment: All faces of this tetrahedron are right triangles. 3 out of 4 right angles are at the vertex.